# ionic input is pushed up when keyboard pops up

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am running my application on ion Devapp and everything seem to be working fine, but when I run it "ionic cordova run android', the ion input changes its position every-time the keyboard pops up. any help please?

I am working with ionic 4.

```
  <ion-row class="search-row">
    <ion-searchbar animated [(ngModel)]="searchText" mode="ios">
    </ion-searchbar>
  </ion-row>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer right after I posted the question, the solution is to change to

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

in the AndroidManifest.xml.

Hope this helps someone!